# DDR4/DDR3 CK and CK# speed ans CLK speek

Tags: pcb, memory, sdram

I am reading the DDR4 specification from Micron but cannot get around one thing:

When you buy RAM and it says DDR4-3200MHz, does it refer to the speed of CK and CK# pins?
I think this is not referring to CK and CK# as 3.2 GHz on a PCB traces is huge...

How fast do CK and CK# pins go?

The internal CLK in the DRAM has CK and CK# as a reference or the DRAM chip generates its own CLK?

Answer (score 3):

> When you buy RAM and it says DDR4-3200MHz, does it refer to the speed of CK and CK# pins?

It refers to the edge rate; that's why it's called *double* data rate. So, that makes the CK pin fulfil a 1600 MHz rectangular wave.

> as 3.2 GHz on a PCB traces is huge

Well, that's why your memory controller has preemphasis and equalization.

Current DDR5 can do up to 3.6 GHz square wave (i.e., 7.2 billion edges a second). This requires significant equalization effort on both ends.

As a comparison to other technologies in your PC: PCIe1 has 2.5 GHz physical symbol rate (i.e., for each lane separately); a DDR4-using motherboard probably has PCIe3.0, which uses 8 GHz per lane. PCIe is *not* DDR, so that's literally 16 billion edges per second. Compared to that, DDR4 is pretty relaxed in bandwidth – DDR4 is much harder to route, however, since you need to align 64 parallel lines to the same length; PCIe is much more tolerant when it comes to inter-lane skew.

> The internal CLK in the DRAM has CK and CK# as a reference or the DRAM chip generates its own CLK?

The actual internal clock rate for the chips in DDR is 1/4 (DDR5: 1/8) of the link speed; so the chips on your DDR4-3200 DIMM run at 400 MHz (These are multiple chips in parallel, and they have an inavoidable latency on responding to commands, so running them slower than link speed, and pipelining request handling as much as possible, makes a lot of sense).